# Content Pane on Landing Page not getting Context

Tags: views, distributions

I thought that would be fairly easy: I am working with Panopoly and I have multiple Landing Pages, a Vocabulary, Content Items and a View with a Content Pane.

The user can select one term per Landing Page (term reference) on creating the lp. Also the content items have one of the terms from the vocabulary attached (as well via term reference).

The View lists all the content items with a contextual filter by term. By default the content pane is part of a newly created Landing Page. So, in this simple case, I want the user to pick a term from the vocabulary and subsequently let the content tagged with this term appear on that landing page via the content pane.

What I get working is the contextual filter "Has taxonomy term ID" with "Argument Input: Input on pane config" Now I can pick a term through the IPE.

However for more complex applications I would like to hand the term selected by the user on creation of the Landing Page (in the edit form) to the content pane, so that the user doesn't have to set it on each content pane seperatly.

Any ideas?

Comment: I try to rephrase the important part:

Comment: On creation of a Landing Page the user selects a term from a vocabulary via term reference. This term shall be used as an argument in a content pane which is part of the Landing Page. 
When I switch the argument input to "Input on pane" and add the argument into the pane via the IPE it works. However, I would like to hand over the argument by context. That's what doesn't work for me.

Comment: I' using the Panopoly distribution on pantheon.io with drupal 7.43, panels 7.x 3.5 and views 7.x 3.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the solution is pretty easy, but due to Views complexity it took my some time to figure it out. In my setup, there is no filter available. My mistake was, that I thought there IS a fitler available which is why I did not fill in the upper section. Since my filter is not in the url, I had to select "Load default filter from node page, that's good for related taxonomy terms".

That's all the magic ;)

[image: Configuration of Contextual Filter]